# Lifting a Sails.js app causes a node.js assertion error

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I recently upgraded Sails.js to the latest version: 0.12.1. While lifting Sails using Nodemon, I get the following error in my Terminal:

```
node.js:262
      if (!x) throw new Error(msg || 'assertion error');
                    ^
Error: assertion error
    at process.assert (node.js:262:21)
    at process.removeListener (node.js:674:9)
    at removeListeners (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/app/lower.js:166:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:713:13
    at iterate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:262:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:274:29
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:718:17
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
    at Server.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/app/lower.js:148:13)
    at Server.g (events.js:199:16)
    at Server.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at net.js:1419:10
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
17 Feb 20:27:03 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I'm not entirely sure what's causing this and none of the other threads on StackOverflow have answers. When I stop the process and restart it by typing `nodemon`, the error goes away. This is my environment:

- Node.js Version: `v0.12.7`
- NPM Version: `2.11.3`
- Sails.js Version: `0.12.1`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope! I even reinstalled Node.js etc. Nothing helped. What about you?

Comment: Nope :(. For me it works on first lift and then when I change a file this error is thrown. I haven't really had time to sit down and try to debug it.